# Android Q, able to connect Wifi pragmatically but not able to access Internet

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, android-internet

In Android Q, I can scan, select and connect to wifi via programmatically. But I am not able to get the internet via the wifi I connected even tho it has internet access.

**Below is my code:**

```
 val wifiNetworkSpecifier = WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
            .setSsid("Wifi-SSID")
            .setWpa2Passphrase("WiFi-password")
            .build()


val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)
            .build()

var connectivityManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

var connectivity = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                Log.d("TAG: ", "Connected")
                connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
                super.onAvailable(network)
            }

            override fun onUnavailable() {
                super.onUnavailable()
                Log.d("TAG: ", "Not able to connect")
            }

            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                Log.d("TAG: ", "Connection lost")
            }
        }
connectivityManager?.requestNetwork(networkRequest, connectivity)
```

TIA

Comment: How exactly did you determine you are not connected to the internet?

Comment: @greeble31  I had added one more simple button which open a webview with Url: https://www.google.com

Comment: How do you know the phone is capable of internet access when your app is not involved?

Comment: For example I connected to ABC wifi manually and tried to open google.com thru Chrome browser and it worked. Then I tried to reconnet the same wifi thru my app and its connected successfully but I am not able to access google.com as its shows no internet available

Comment: I had read a couple of articles says that this is an Android Q bug and will be fixed in couple of months. So is there any workaround that I can follow?

Comment: Hmm, please mention some of those articles, because I have never heard of this.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138335744 --> please go through this link

Comment: I think [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138335744#comment8) answers your question. You cannot do this, using this API, in Android Q.

Comment: Can you re-share the link, I am getting Access denied pop-up message.

Comment: Now the original link is blocked as well :) I think we broke it :) IIRC, it said the internet access was intentionally disabled when using `requestNetwork()` to force a connection to a given access point, and that internet would only be available to networks cooperatively chosen with input from the user, such as via the [Wi-Fi suggest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-suggest.md) API. See also [this doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/features#peer2peer).

Comment: I even tried with [Wi-Fi suggest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-suggest.md) API. But it doesn't work for me.